# Store variable data after query with mongoose and node.js

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, express, mongoose

I have code in `app.js`

```
    var Song = db.model('Song');
    var Album = db.model('Album');
```

I want to render to `index.jade` with 2 variables are `list of song` and `list of album`

 I use query like this

```
Song.find({}, function( err, docs ){
// .........
}
Album.find({}, function( err, docs ){
// .........
}
```

So, what should i do to store `list of song` and `list of album` to `variables` and render to `index.jade` with 2 lists

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you mean something like this:

```
function( req, res ) { // whatever your "controller" function is
  Song.find({}, function( err, songs ){
    Album.find({}, function( err, albums ){
      res.render('index', { song_list: songs, album_list: albums });
    });
  }); 
}
```

Then just iterate and markup your `song_list` and `album_list` arrays in the template.

Note that this is synchronous and therefore slower than an async approach, but it should do what you want. To go the async route, consider using a library like this to defer `res.render` until both queries are done: https://github.com/kriszyp/promised-io

Comment: Hi, Jed, could u help me to resolve problem in [HERE](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8754597/what-should-i-do-to-store-data-to-session-with-connect-redis)